# What happened to Connie?

Tags: character, independence-day-resurgence

In the Independence Day movie, David Levinson (Jeff Goldblum) went YEARS after his  divorce from Connie without removing the wedding ring, and he couldn't get her off his mind!

In Independence Day 2: Resurgence, in 2016? He has seemingly retconned her out of his life entirely, it seems!

What happened to his marriage with Connie? Is this ever explained in the movie? Where is she?

Bonus: Why do you suppose no one ever talked about her in the movie?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea. I think someone needs to ask Dean Devlin or Roland Emmerich. Someone had asked Jeff Goldblum. He had replied that the movie would explain. But it never did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be depressing to hear, but according to the description in the Wikipedia article for the second movie, she died. If you go to Charlotte Gainsbourg in the article, it mentions she is David's new love interest. It then proceeds to describe that he remarried Connie. But then she died in a car accident.  This is sourced, which is part of the Independence Day Crucible book.

In the movie, they never mention this.  Basically, I think they pulled the Will Smith treatment without the acknowledgement that she passed away.